# javascript visualizing/drawing image loading progress with progressjs script

Tags: javascript, image, load, progress-bar, percentage

i want to use progressjs for my gif images.
this is the source of progressjs:

http://usablica.github.io/progress.js/

https://github.com/usablica/progress.js/wiki/API

i dont understand how can i use this script for my images like the above example page...

this is my html:

```
<img src="http://i.giphy.com/2mjvyqAihU77y.gif" class="vp-list-image">

<img src="http://i.giphy.com/xRkPrKXyz65yM.gif" class="vp-list-image">

<img src="http://i.giphy.com/9oi8jhRRsDA3e.gif" class="vp-list-image">
```

and this is my script to start and to end the blue progress bar:

```
progressJs(".vp-list-image").setOptions({overlayMode: true, theme: 'blue'}).start().autoIncrease(1, 100);

if(window.onload) {
    var curronload = window.onload;
    var newonload = function() {
        curronload();
        progressJs().end();
    };
    window.onload = newonload;
} else {
    window.onload = function(){ progressJs().end(); };
}
```

with these codes, progress bars starting on the gif images, but, bars dissapears after the last gif loaded

and a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0cbr8jaf/

(on a web page, bars dissapears after page loaded)

Comment: is there anyone else to help me?

Comment: i want to cry :...(